# How to use gatsby sitemap on Amplify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localization, gatsby, xml-sitemap

I'm using "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^2.4.2" tho, it doesn't work after install "gatsby-plugin-intl": "^0.3.3" on Amplify even tho it works on Local env well.

This is the URL, but automatically it's moved to https://www.babylook.mom/.

https://www.babylook.mom/sitemap.xml

Below is the gatsby-config.js

```
{
   resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`,
   options: {
     output: `/sitemap.xml`,
   }
},
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-intl`,
  options: {
    path: `${__dirname}/src/intl`,
    languages: [`en`, `es`, `zh`],
    defaultLanguage: `en`,
    redirect: false,
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin's order is important in Gatsby, try putting the `gatsby-plugin-intl` above since it's the one in charge of prefix all the URLs with the provided locales:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-intl`,
  options: {
    path: `${__dirname}/src/intl`,
    languages: [`en`, `es`, `zh`],
    defaultLanguage: `en`,
    redirect: false,
  },
},  
{
   resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`,
   options: {
     output: `/sitemap.xml`,
   }
},
```

In addition, you may want to explore all the query options that the [`gatsby-plugin-sitemap` provides](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-sitemap/#options).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried to add all query options and also change the plugin order. However, the sitemap doesn't appear. Instead of it, it's moved to the top url.